# Insert href and img in javascript code

Tags: javascript, html

I created a website and in this moment I have a problem with javascript
In my code I have this

```
<script language="JavaScript"><!--
    function ChangeMessage(message,champ)  {
      if(document.getElementById)
        document.getElementById(champ).innerHTML = message;  }
    //-->
</script>



<td BGCOLOR="#000000"><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="datisto"  onclick="ChangeMessage('&lt;br /&gt; &lt;div class=\'histo2\'&gt;Documents à présenter si l’enfant voyage avec ses deux parents.  &lt;br /&gt; &lt;br /&gt; Téléchargez le formulaire de consentement parental affabit &lt;br /&gt;  &lt;br /&gt; a href=http://www.consulfrance-jhb.org/IMG/pdf/parentalconsentaffidavit-3.pdf?1364/e3c77d3aecaad00eac194f0cc42f625f8c97febb class=button','ejs_texte')"><img src="images/8.jpg" height=150 width=100></a></td>
```

In the code I can display text by changing the color , but I don't see how i can insert a `href` link or picture inside `changeMessage`

Comment: Sorry I don't write my question, my question is: In the code I can display text by changing the color , but I don't see how i can insert a " href " link or picture inside " changeMessage "

Comment: You've not opened or closed an `<a>` in your string, you need the `<` and `>`, or `&lt;` and `&gt;` for your `<a>` tag and to include some content and the close tag

Comment: &lt;/a href=http://www.consulfrance-jhb.org/IMG/pdf/parentalconsentaffidavit-3.pdf?1364/e3c77d3aecaad00eac194f0cc42f625f8c97febb class=button &gt; &lt;/span class=download &gt; Download','ejs_texte')    like this exemple

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = document.getElementById('yourlinkId'); //or grab it by tagname etc
a.href = "somelink url"
```